# How to extend Hangfire Dashboard using MVC

Tags: hangfire

I found this link on extending Hangfire's dashboard:
https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/dashboard-extension/1371/2
But it uses an approach where you write html literals.

Is there a way to extend the dashboard using MVC's Controllers/Views ?